# How can use CD command in command prompt to change to a folder named only with a space?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, whitespace

I'm creating a Batch-file and I want go into a directory named only with whitespace e.g.:

```
"D:/Drive/ "
```

I tried with `""`,`''`,`"/"` and `"%20"` but nothing worked.

How can I do this?

Comment: How did you create an folder named only with a single whitespace? I tried to reproduce this over the editor and over the cmd and windows doesn't allow the creation of an folder named like this.

Comment: I had to generate the folder through the built-in Linux subsystem. So far all I've been able to figure out is that you can do things with folders and files in the ` ` folder, but you have to use full paths instead of entering the folder.

Comment: IMHO the bottom line should be: *never* define a folder called `space`, even in Linux!

Comment: As interesting as this is, what is the use case for having a directory named with a SPACE character? The only things I can think of involve some form of obfuscation. It is usually better to make things more clear rather than more complex.

Comment: Actually I did not create a folder, but Trojan create it in my pen drive and many in my office. I want to create "bat" file to replace folder structure back, which virus guard doesn't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to create the directory with a [fully-qualified path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths) by `mkdir "\\?\D:\ "`. However that folder can't be accessed by either Explorer or cmd

In Windows Explorer entering the folder always show the parent folder's content although it has actually entered the subfolder, therefore you can't do anything with that content, and Explorer's title bar becomes blank since it displays the folder name. In cmd `cd` stays on the parent folder unless you use the trick in [SomethingDark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981713/995714). You probably need to remove or rename it

Sad to say I've yet to find a way to rename the folder. However it's easy to delete it with the same path

```
rmdir "\\?\D:\ "
```

A normal path will also work but you ***always need a slash at the end***

```
mkdir ".\ \"
rmdir ".\ \"
```

It's possible to ***store files in that folder***

```
D:\>>".\ \a.txt" echo abc

D:\>type ".\ \a.txt"
abc
```

Once you have some content in the folder Explorer can now enter it normally. Unfortunately cmd still can't change into it. A fully-qualified path may help, unluckily cmd doesn't support it. However **PowerShell does support it and can enter it like Explorer**

```
PS D:\> cat '.\ \a.txt'
abc
PS D:\> cd '.\ \'
cd : An object at the specified path D:\  does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd '.\ \'
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

PS D:\> cd '\\?\D:\ \'
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\?\D:\ > dir


    Directory: \\?\D:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        8/23/2018   3:39 PM              5 a.txt
```

Sadly once you entered you can't use `cd ..` to go back and you must use fully-qualified path again

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\?\D:\ > cd ..
cd : Cannot find path '\\?\D:' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd ..
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\?\D::String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\?\D:\ > echo `"$(pwd)`"
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\?\D:\ "
```

Answer (score 1):

Uh well this is a kind of special case since Windows does not allow folder and file names to begin with a space.

As Paxz mentioned in his comment, I also was not able to reproduce this so I'm just going to assume that you used a no-break space?

In that case you would use this syntax: `cd " "` but hold up.

You can't just press space here, you will need to hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then press <kbd>0160</kbd> while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> down. Also don't forget that you need to use the numbers from the Num Block on the right of your keyboard.

Comment: It is both, disturbing and interesting that this is allowed... I hope I never encounter anyone using this... Gj @Tibix

Comment: @Paxz yeah i agree with you this should not be a thing, thanks :)

Comment: I can make the folder with a single space, but Windows doesn't allow access to that. Note that code point 160 is a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), which is not a normal space

Comment: @Tibix Folder and file names can begin with one or more __normal__ space characters as it can be seen on running in a command prompt window `echo Hello!>"  Hello.txt  "` and `md "  Folder with Spaces  "`. Some higher level functions of Windows just trim __trailing__ whitespaces before passing the file/folder name to low level functions creating the file/folder. A file/folder name with just normal spaces is trimmed to an empty string causing unexpected behavior like this one.

Answer (score 1):

To enter a directory called , you need to use `cd " \ \"`. I have no idea why you need to do it twice.

[image]

Note that under ordinary circumstances, this would never be possible. However, if the folder was created on Linux and then copied over, Windows would do its best to make it work.