# Why doesn't PowerShell Core 7 recognize UNC paths when Windows PowerShell and cmd do?

Tags: powershell, path, filesystems, powershell-core

It appears that PowerShell does not recognize the `\\?\` notation. Why not?

=== cmd.exe

```
C:>ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1935]
C:>DIR "\\?\C:\Users\*"
 Volume in drive \\?\C: is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 1C66-809A

 Directory of \\?\C:\Users

2021-08-04  12:27    <DIR>          .
2021-08-04  12:27    <DIR>          ..
2019-11-25  16:22    <DIR>          Administrator
...               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              28 Dir(s)  81,919,647,744 bytes free
```

=== Windows powershell.exe

```
PS C:\Users> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
5.1.17763.1852
PS C:\Users> Get-ChildItem -Path "\\?\C:\Users\*"

    Directory: \\?\C:\Users

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2019-11-25     15:22                Administrator
...
PS C:\Users>
```

=== PowerShell Core pwsh.exe

```
PS C:\Users> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.1.4
PS C:\Users> Get-ChildItem -Path "\\?\C:\Users\*"
PS C:\Users>
```

Comment: I don't know why but `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\?\C:\Users\"` works so probably something related to the wildcard matching in `-Path`

Comment: "Why" is easily answered with "because it was written that way"; if you want to know if it's intended or a bug (and if it is a bug, if it's going to be fixed), the [PowerShell repo](https://github.com/powershell/powershell) seems like a better bet than SO. A little bit of searching gave me [#10805](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10805), which looks like it covers this.

Comment: @phuclv, if you look closely, in PS Core `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\?\C:\Users\"` doesn't actually work: while it does produce output, it mistakenly reports the _root_ directory's content (verified on PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your path syntax is **unrelated to *UNC*** paths; it uses a **special prefix<sup>[1]</sup>, `\\?\`, whose purpose is to *opt into* support for file-system paths whose length exceeds `259` characters**.

**In *Windows PowerShell*** (the legacy PowerShell edition that ships with Windows, whose latest and *final* version is v5.1):

- `\\?\` *is* supported, as shown in your question.

---

**In *PowerShell (Core) 6+*** (the cross-platform, install-on-demand edition):

- **`\\?\` is *no longer needed*, because long paths are supported *by default***.
- That said, **it should still be *supported*** - not least in order to support code that runs in *both* PowerShell editions - and the fact that **it isn't, as of PowerShell 7.2** - situationally resulting in *no* output, with *wildcard* paths, `Get-ChildItem -Path \\?\C:\Users\*`, or with the *root* directory's content(!), with *literal* paths `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath \\?\C:\Users` - is the subject of [GitHub issue #10805](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10805).

---

<sup>[1] Such prefixes identify Win32 *namespaces*. The specifics of `\\?\` are explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-file-namespaces).</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Given this convention is specific to Win32 (and PowerShell has been re-written to be cross-platform), it is likely that this is simply not supported any longer.

If you have other parts of the code that expect this format, a well-placed inline `-replace` can strip it off

```
$("\\?\C:\Users\*" -replace '\\\\\?\\', '')
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with the URI format. It's the [fully-qualified name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#namespaces)

Comment: The \\?\ prefix disables file name normalization so you can create files with very long path, or files with invalid characters (because NTFS is fully POSIX-compatible and allows files with any characters except NUL and `/`) [Where is the use of “\\?\” defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68044243/995714), [Why can't I mkdir \\?\%temp%\very\long\path in cmd.exe?](https://superuser.com/q/1410627/241386), [How can use CD command in command prompt to change to a folder named only with a space?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981367/995714)

Comment: per the link:
`Many but not all file I/O APIs support "\\?\"; you should look at the reference topic for each API to be sure.`

given this is Win32 documentation, probably best to avoid it as PowerShell has been rewritten to be cross-platform.

@phuclv -- thanks for the links -- used that info to update my answer.

Comment: actually the file name is received by `FileSystemProvider` which calls `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` and ends up in the `Find­First­File` and `FindNextFile` in the Windows implementation which understands \\?\ so the path format shouldn't affect the output. And this still doesn't answer the question which is why it occurs

Comment: The short of it: PowerShell Core no longer _needs_ the `\\?\ ` prefix, because it supports long paths _by default_. However, the prefix should still be _supported_ - not least in order to facilitate writing _cross-edition_ code - and the fact that it _isn't_ as of v7.2 should be considered a _bug_ - see [GitHub issue #](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10805). /cc @phuclv